# Howto remove html entity from the csv file while upload?

Tags: php, csv, html-entities

I'm trying to upload csv file, it uploads the csv, but the data are not correct.

How can I convert this into just string and remove the `& lt;p&gt ;` or the `&lt;p&gt;`?

Example of my csv file data:

```
**&lt;p&gt;\DECO APPLE GRN IN WOODEN CRATE SIZE 34X25X15.5CM PLASTIC&lt;/p&gt;\**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
$sample_string = '**&lt;p&gt;\DECO APPLE GRN IN WOODEN CRATE SIZE 34X25X15.5CM PLASTIC&lt;/p&gt;\**';
echo strip_tags(html_entity_decode($sample_string));
// **\DECO APPLE GRN IN WOODEN CRATE SIZE 34X25X15.5CM PLASTIC\**
```

Application (if it's not malformed):

```
$data = array();
if (($handle = fopen('sample.csv', 'r')) !== false) {
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 4096, ',', "\n")) !== false) {
        $data[] = array_map(function($var){
            return strip_tags(html_entity_decode($var));
        }, $row);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => PROD.product_id
        [1] => PROD.sync_2
        [2] => PROD.quantity
        [3] => PROD_DESC.name
        [4] => PROD_DESC.description
        [5] => PROD_DISC.price
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => ABCD
        [2] => 2570
        [3] => VIP
        [4] => "\ DECO APPLE GRN IN WOODEN CRATE SIZE 34X25X15.5CM PLASTIC\"
        [5] => 0.848
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => ABCDEFG
        [2] => 2570
        [3] => VIP 2
        [4] => "\ DECO APPLE GRN IN WOODEN CRATE SIZE 34X25X15.5CM PLASTIC\"
        [5] => 10
    )
)
```

Comment: @user3803889 yes? where is the CSV file? i think that's much easier to examine

Comment: How can I add a csv file here sir?

Comment: @user3803889 if its too big, you don't need to put it in here, instead use [this](http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: @user3803889 is this the raw csv file? the new lines are all over the place, its not properly terminated by a newline

Comment: Yes that's the sample of the csv's raw file. I can't edit them because they are more that 20,000. So I need to edit them via code.

Comment: @user3803889 so it's like that in the first place?, your csv should be lined up correctly, check [this](http://pastebin.com/wu1jzjMB)

Comment: @user3803889 usually, rows are pretty much lined up properly, iknow its a bit off topic, so this is the only copy you can work with, that's a pain to edit since as you have said thats 20,000+

Comment: I have another question, can I make a progress bar while uploading the csv? For example, "1000 of 30000"???

Comment: @user3803889 of course this is a separate question, but to give you an idea, check this out [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049303/show-progress-for-php-long-script), probably there are some other good answers here on SO

Comment: Can you give me a code using code igniter? Because I'm new to code igniter.

Comment: @user3803889 about csv? i don't know if codeigniter has wrapper functions for csv, check out their [manual](http://www.ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/), if they have one.