# PHP and AJAX: Echo during process

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, logging, echo

little issue over here.

I have a php function that is called via AJAX and looks like this:

```
function processActiveDirectory(){
    $var = new GetLDAPUsers;

    echo "Getting Users from Active Directory.... <br />";        

    $adusers = $var->getAllUsers();
    echo "setting up images.... <br />";
    // processing more stuff
    echo "finished";
}
```

I'm trying to get a "live- log" echo. Meaning before every step the echo should output to a Log area, one step after another. So the user knows what's going on.

But the Problem is, that the log doesn't appear during the process, it just fills in at the whole text at the end of the process. Everything else works fine. The Log just doesn't appear at runtime, but after the function is finished it appears at the right position.

My AJAX call:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#lii-form').submit(function() {
        data = {
            action: 'lii_map_images'
        };

        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response){
            $('#lii_log').html(response);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

This is how it's build:

[image: Ajax and PHP File]

**Edit**

Other than in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049303/show-progress-for-php-long-script) I'm already using an ajax call, to call the function. It's within the called function that I'm echoing stuff...

**Edit 2**

I'm using wordpress

Sorry I can't offer more informations, because of enterprise restrictments.

Comment: Is it cross-domain ?

Comment: it's all on the same domain

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show progress for PHP long script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049303/show-progress-for-php-long-script)

Comment: check this: http://invisiblezero.net/javascript-continuously-respectively-send-requests-to-server/

Comment: @Thamilan almost, but I'm already using the php- process is already started via an ajax- call. I tried flushing the buffer but with no success

Answer (score 4):

This is a short over-view on your need. Please develop further with this idea.

This uses two AJAX calling - one for the main process and other for progress:

**Script:**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Start the main process
    $.ajax({
        url: 'main.php',
        success: function(data) {
        }
    });

    function getProgress(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'progress.php',
            success: function(data) {
                $("#progress").html(data);
                if(data != "finished"){
                    getProgress();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //Start the progress section
    getProgress();
</script>
<div id="progress"></div>
```

**main.php**

```
<?php
$arr = ['Getting Users from Active Directory....','setting up images....','finished'];
foreach($arr as $value) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["progress"]=$value;
    session_write_close();
    sleep(1);
}
```

**progress.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
sleep(1);
echo $_SESSION["progress"];
```

So your `processActiveDirectory` will come under `Main.php` and echo should be replaced with `SESSION` variable

Comment: like this?  $adusers = $var->getAllUsers();     $_SESSION["progress"]= "setting up images.... <br />";

Comment: @Zanidd Yes, Remember to start and write close the session for every progress update, only then it is detected. (Am trying to find an alternative for multiple start and close)

Comment: It didn't really translate that well into my code, I think it's mainly because it's a wordpress thing

Comment: hi, in recent days, is there any new and advance technique instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need in such thing as LOG process WITH AJAX. AJAX is too heavy thing and it could be a bad design if you want it. It's better to use web sockets or not use at all